# Does using a path from system, while calling a file, cause crashes?

Tags: ios

I've a text file that stores my app's data for me.

If I use system path `(/Users/username/Desktop/ProjectFile/data.txt)`, can it cause errors when application compiled into .ipa file?

Comment: If file present while Creating iPA then it will compile but If you delete the File and Compile it will give error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using path form system like in the question causes crash when tested on a real iOS device.

Instead of using system path, using the code below will be more advantageous. It prevents crashes on real device.

```
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("file", ofType: "txt")
        let fileMgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        var array: [String] = []

        if fileMgr.fileExistsAtPath(path!) {
            do {
                let text = try! String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
                array = text.componentsSeparatedByString("|#|")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

open the file in your project, and check the target membership, as shown in following image. If target membership icon is checked for your corresponding target, then it will not make any problem during compilation(creating ipa). But if target membership is unchecked for your target build, then it will make the problem.

[image]

Comment: It is checked but when I try to compile and test it on a real test device I got "no such file" error. It runs on simulator without an error.